# Processing the output from Array Count Values

Tags: php

I have an array of categories.

Array_Count_Values lists them with how many times they each appear within the array. I.E: 
`[Gas] => 1 [Electricity] => 4 [Car] => 3...`

Essentially I want to output that, but process the string so that it says...

```
<a href=?cat=gas>gas</a>(1) ~ <a href=?cat=electricity>Electricity</a>(4) ~ ...etc
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the value of the `cat` param determined by `strtolower()`'ing (and presumably also `urlencode()`'ing) the category name, or is there a different way they are mapped?

Comment: It will actually be a corresponding numerical variable instead - but will be urlencoded. I'm just trying to work out which function to use to get the data out of the array! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but one solution for what you are literally asking:

```
<?php

foreach ($Array_Count_Values as $item => $count)
{
   if ($count != 0)
        echo " ~ ";
   echo "<a href=\"?cat=$item>$item</a>($count)";
}
```